# Would a dictionary or list of tuples be more efficient for this particular task?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I wrote a script whose aim is to find the parameters best fitting a function by trial and error (a Markov Chain Monte Carlo). The viability of the parameters is judged by a chi value -- the lower the chi, the better.

Below is a section of my code as currently written:

```
chi1 = fun_chi(B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01)
BGCchilist = []
count = -1

for i in range(iteration_MCMC):
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    B2,G2,C12,C22,C32,C42,C02 = gen_param(B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01)
    chi2 = fun_chi(B2,G2,C12,C22,C32,C42,C02)
    ratio = np.exp((-chi2 + chi1) / 2)
    rand = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if rand < ratio:
        B1 = B2
        G1 = G2
        C11 = C12
        C21 = C22
        C31 = C32
        C41 = C42
        C01 = C02
        chi1 = chi2
    ##save the data
    Bsave = B1
    Gsave = G1
    C1save = C11
    C2save = C21
    C3save = C31
    C4save = C41
    C0save = C01
    chisave = chi1
    BGCchilist.append((Bsave,Gsave,C1save,C2save,C3save,C4save,C0save,chisave))

Blist = [x[0] for x in BGCchilist]
Glist = [x[1] for x in BGCchilist]
C1list = [x[2] for x in BGCchilist]
C2list = [x[3] for x in BGCchilist]
C3list = [x[4] for x in BGCchilist]
C4list = [x[5] for x in BGCchilist]
C0list = [x[6] for x in BGCchilist]
chilist = [x[7] for x in BGCchilist]
minchi = min(x[7] for x in BGCchilist)
mintuple = [x for x in BGCchilist if x[7] == minchi]
```

I ultimately individually graph all of those lists versus iteration via Matplotlib and then save `mintuple` as a text file.

A colleague took a look at this and told me that perhaps I would be better served by using a dictionary, where for every iteration I do something like `a_dictionary[chisave] = (B,G,...C0)` and then find `mintuple` by looking for the minimum value in the dictionary. However, it seems like extracting lists from the value tuples in the dictionary for graphing would be more unwieldy and take more steps.

Would the dictionary approach allow for fewer steps, greater efficiency, or is this all lists approach okay as is?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Given that you all do this in plain Python, not through numpy or scipy, I don't think efficiency matters very much in that last step. If you're looking for the best-fit parameters, why don't you just compare the chi values, and store a single tuple with the best parameters (overridden everytime the new chi value is better). No need to store all those intermediate values.

Comment: Further, assuming that the chi value is a floating point value, I wouldn't use that as a dictionary key. I would also not use that in the comparison at the very last line.

Comment: Evert, I need to store the intermediate values because my boss wants to see graphs capturing the search trajectories for each parameter (parameter value vs. iteration). Interesting -- why are fp values bad as keys? I have heard that lists cannot be use as keys, but not fp values.

Comment: When using a float as a key in a dict you just need to be careful on how you later get a float to use as the lookup.  If you're doing math to create the float the odds are against you (you are unlikely to get the exact same float from different floating point operations).  In the case of my answer, though, you are getting the lookup key directly from the keys already in the dict, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: Isn't it a little easier to use inplace expansion here? You can just have a tuple of parameters `par1 = B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01` in the first line, and then go: `chi1 = fun_chi(*par1)`. Then later, `par2 = gen_param(*par1)`. Later, there is no need for individual assignments. You can just assign tuples like so: `if rand < ratio: par1 = par2`. Finally, there is no need for appending by saving in different variables first. You can just do: `BGCchilist.append(par1)`.

Comment: Finally, for the last result, you can just use `zip` in the form of `BList, ... = zip(*BGCchilist)`. I think your code will end up being a few lines, and much more readable ...

Comment: One more thing: there is no need of the variable `count`. You can just `print i-1`.

Comment: ssm, so you recommend that I stick with tuples and that there is no need to go for a dictionary?

Comment: Actually, yeah, I will have to go with tuples, because I just found out that dictionaries reorder the sequence of entries by ascending key value, if the keys are ints or floats.

Comment: Any particular run of Python will have the keys ordered consistently, but randomly.

Comment: @ssm: You should make an answer so it can be voted on.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Just added the answer. The absence of newline separators in the comments are really unwieldily. In an actual answer the ideas are more easier to lay down. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @potpie: That is my suggestion yes. The algorithm you are computing in this part of the code is really simple. There is no need of extravagant data structures. You are essentially working with 7 sets of numbers which go together as a group. Both Tuples and Lists would do the job. I generally keep things simple so that I can see the logical flow of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is making an answer out of the comments. I thought that the question about the efficiency but after closer examination, it looks like it is about how to clean up the code. If that is the confer, then the following might be useful:

For the first part, we just keep everything as a tuple, and use inlace expansion like so ...

```
par1 = B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01
chi1 = fun_chi(*par1)
BGCchilist = []

for i in range(iteration_MCMC):

    print (i-1)

    par2  = gen_param(*par1)
    chi2  = fun_chi(*par2)
    ratio = np.exp((-chi2 + chi1) / 2)
    rand  = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if rand < ratio: par1 = par2
    BGCchilist.append(list(par1) + [chi1]) ##save the data
```

This is a verbatim logical copy. However, I don't see chi1 being updated within the `for` loop. I am guessing that you want that  to happen as well? Like so:

```
par1 = B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01
BGCchilist = []

for i in range(iteration_MCMC):

    print (i-1)

    chi1  = fun_chi(*par1) # This is the change
    par2  = gen_param(*par1)
    chi2  = fun_chi(*par2)

    if np.random.uniform(0,1) < np.exp((-chi2 + chi1) / 2): par1 = par2

    BGCchilist.append(list(par1) + [chi1]) ##save the data
```

I am not sure about the algorithm, so cannot definitively comment on that part.

The next part is more interesting.

```
Blist    = [x[0] for x in BGCchilist]
Glist    = [x[1] for x in BGCchilist]
C1list   = [x[2] for x in BGCchilist]
C2list   = [x[3] for x in BGCchilist]
C3list   = [x[4] for x in BGCchilist]
C0list   = [x[6] for x in BGCchilist]
C4list   = [x[5] for x in BGCchilist]
chilist  = [x[7] for x in BGCchilist]
```

can be simply replaced by:

```
BList,  GList,           \
C1List, C2List, C3List   \
C0List, C4List, chilist  = zip(*BGCchilist)
```

I think this is what it does. Please check this part separately.

Finally, do you really need all the lists? Or do you just need the `chiList` ?

The rest should be easy I think? What you have is pretty ok. Check the `key` parameter in the `min` function. So if you dont want all the lists for some reason, you can simply skip that part and find the minimum within the for loop, or you can just do:

```
minChi     = min( zip(*BGCchilist)[-1] )
allMinChis = filter( lambda m: m[7] == minChi, BGCchilist)
```

Cheeers!

N.B. I havent tested the code so there might be errors. Please go through the code and make sure that that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A `dict` will be fewer steps, and be easier to read as well.  Using `minchi` as the key:

```
BGCchilist = {}

# in the loop

    BGCchilist[chisave] = [Bsave, Gsave, C1save,C2save,C3save,C4save,C0save,chisave]

# out of the loop

minchi = min(BGCchilist.keys())
mintuple = BGCchilist[minchi]
```

If you need to save each combination of parameters that result in the same chi value, change the dict to hold a list of tuples per key, instead of just a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

BGCchilist = defaultdict(list)

...

    BGCchilist[chisave].append([...all the saves...])

...

minchi = min(BGCchilist.keys())
mintuples = BGCchilist[minchi]
# at this point mintuples has at least one tuple of params that got
# this chi score, maybe more
```

Update:

Okay, so here's my understanding of your requirements:

- you need to save each combination of parameters and the resulting chi score
- you need to get the lowest chi score when done
- you need a list of each input parameter, and the chi scores, when done

I would use a simple class for this.  It might not be fewer lines, but it will be much more readable:

```
# lightly tested
class BGCChiData(object):  # (object) not needed in Python3
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = defaultdict(list)
    def __getitem__(self, chi):
        return self.data[chi]
    def __setitem__(self, chi, params):
        self.data[chi].append(params)
    @property
    def min_chi(self):
        return min(self.data.keys())
    @property
    def B(self):
        return [tup[0] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def G(self):
        return [tup[1] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def C1(self):
        return [tup[2] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def C2(self):
        return [tup[3] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def C3(self):
        return [tup[4] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def C4(self):
        return [tup[5] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def C0(self):
        return [tup[6] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]
    @property
    def chi(self):
        return [tup[7] for val in self.data.values() for tup in val]

chi1 = fun_chi(B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01)
BGCchi = BGCChiData()

for count in range(iteration_MCMC):
    print(count)
    B2,G2,C12,C22,C32,C42,C02 = gen_param(B1,G1,C11,C21,C31,C41,C01)
    chi2 = fun_chi(B2,G2,C12,C22,C32,C42,C02)
    ratio = np.exp((-chi2 + chi1) / 2)
    rand = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if rand < ratio:
        B1 = B2
        G1 = G2
        C11 = C12
        C21 = C22
        C31 = C32
        C41 = C42
        C01 = C02
        chi1 = chi2
    ##save the data
    BGCchi[chi1].append(B1, G1, C11, C21, C31, C41, C01)

minchi = BGCchi.min_chi
mintuple = BGCchi[minchi]
B1list = BGCchi.B
# etc. etc.
```

Comment: Ethan, how would I extract the entries from the value tuples to create the individual lists for each parameter? From `{chi1:[C1,...CN],chi2:[C1,...CN],...chiN:[C1,...CN]}` I need to get a list that contains all `C1`'s, one that contains all `C2`'s and so forth.